# Parked domain redirect

Tags: redirect

I'm a bit lost on how to handle this redirect requirement.

So far I have:

- www.domain-B.com parked on www.domain-A.com
- So, requests for www.domain-B.com/page1 resolve to www.domain-A.com/page1 and so on
- So far so good

However I would like one exception to this:

- If user requests the root of www.domain-B.com, I would like them to go to www.domain-A.com/pageX

So everything works as normal with a parked domain *except* when a user goes to the root url of the parked domain.

I've tried the redirect plugin for WP but when redirecting www.domain-B.com to www.domain-A.com/pageX it actually redirects www.domain-A.com to that page as well. (because its properly parked I guess!)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Hi **@user2924:**

Use the `'template_redirect'` hook; put the following in your theme's 'functions.php' file:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yoursite_template_redirect' );
function yoursite_template_redirect() {
  if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])=='www.domain-b.com')
    wp_safe_redirect('http://www.domain-a.com/pagex'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @user2924 - Did it work for you? Also since you are a new user be sure to follow up, see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: OK, looked like it was working but I hadn't un-istalled the plugin.  So now with no redirect plugins and the code above it does not work for me.  It is as if WP does not know the request is coming from domain-b as it just sits on the regular home page. Ideas?

Comment: @user2924 - Doh! I forgot to add `exit;`. :-)

Comment: :-) Unfortunately it either results in a blank page, or if I try alternative url formats in the function i.e. (www.doma...) (http://domain...) (http://www.domain....) I either get an error where the URL parsed is too long or taken to the WP admin page, not the specified redirect page....hmmmm

Comment: @user2924 Can you use `echo` and `exit` statements to debug the values? Maybe your setup differs from the default and my approach missed something?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel sorry but how do I use echo here?  I've been trying but nothing is output so I know I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @user2924 - For example `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` before the `if`, and `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` before the `exit;`.